# Dart how to match and then replace a regexp

Tags: regex, dart

This may be a silly question, but I can't find any reference on how to replace a text after being matched by a regexp using Dart's `RegExp`.

Basically what I'm trying to do is like this:
I have a text like this

```
'{name : aName, hobby : [fishing, playing_guitar]}'
```

I want to match the string using this pattern `\b\w+\b`, then replace using `"$&"`. I expect the output to be like:

```
'{"name" : "aName", "hobby" : ["fishing", "playing_guitar"]}'
```

So later I can use `dart:json`'s `parse` to turn that to a `Map`.

Maybe I missed something. Does anyone know how I can achieve this replacement?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You have to use [String.replaceAllMapped](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.20.1/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html).

```dart
final string = '{name : aName, hobby : [fishing, playing_guitar]}';
final newString = string.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'\b\w+\b'), (match) {
  return '"${match.group(0)}"';
});
print(newString);
```

This recipe is sponsored by [Dart Cookbook](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/cookbook/#substituting-strings-using-regular-expressions).

Comment: The regrex is not correct with url in the json string. For example:
'{name: aName, website: https://awebsite.com}'

it returns something like '{"name": "aName", "website": "https": "//awebsite.com"}'

Comment: @SimonPham I don't think this answer is intended to work on arbitrary JSON, only the particular string given by the OP. You can use `r'\b[\w:.\/]+\b'` to match your new format, but it's easy to add more edge cases to break that, too and kick the can further. You'd probably have to write a parser if the complexity is arbitrary, and that's out of scope of the thread and requirements posted by OP.